# How to use reflection to get keys from Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection

Tags: vb.net, debugging, system.reflection

I know that it is not possible to get keys ([How to get the Key and Value from a Collection VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7500162/669527)) and it is better to use other classes. However I am debugging 10 years old code and I cannot change it.

In the Watch Window I see:
[image]

So it seems to be possible to deal the collection as "`List(of KeyValuePair)`". Can I do it in code or is it only an internal translation.

**I basically need to list all KEYs in a Collection.**

Comment: As I said I am *debugging* not rewriting. When I am allowed I use newer types.

Comment: My suggestion has nothing to do with what you are doing exacly; if you have to write a new code anyway, better using the most efficient solution, isn't it? If you rely on Reflection, the required code would be longer/more difficult and the resulting performance would be slower. On the other hand, if you change the type of the collection, you might perform any actions you wish without any problem. You might even create a new collection (originalColl_v2), populate it with the values from the original one, use it to debug and thus don't affect the original code at all.

Comment: @varocarbas I am writing a Debugger Visualiser. Original code MUST remain intouched.

Comment: Actually I was misled by your question (and the link you provided). Collection is not the equivalent to Dictionary, but to List. You can access any item without any problem and the corresponding index; by bearing in mind that the indices start from 1.

Comment: @varocarbas I am looking for a **KEY**. I know that I can get a value by index. Look at the image. Keys are there.

Comment: And what is the KEY of a List? The index (a List is a Dictionary where the Keys are a bunch on consecutive integers; in this case, starting from 1): `Dim test = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection
test.Add("val1")
Dim valAtKey1 As String = test(1)`

Comment: I want to list key besides values. I the watch is collection displayed as list of **keyvalue pairs**. Look at the image(I appologize for its readability but you can enlarge it). I am not saying that list has a key.

Comment: After a couple of tests, this is trickier than what I thought. Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection does not seem to behave as old VB/VBA collections (as a List), but as some kind of Dictionary, also accepting strings as Keys. The most surprising thing is that the type of its elements (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.KeyValuePair) does not seem to be properly recognised by VB.NET: you cannot declare a variable with this type neither it can be casted to a "conventional" KeyValuePair...

Comment: ... there is even a more surprising fact, if you intend to get the type (e.g., Dim testType As Type = collection(1).GetType()), you get "string"!?. There seems to not be a way through. You cannot use Reflection because any analysis starts from the Type (and the Type is not being recognised!!). As said above, (old) Collections are expected to be used as List (Keys a list of consecutive integers) and this is the feature "properly supported" by VB.NET. If you use them as Dictionaries (which seems also to be allowed), you would get in a kind of buggy situation. Hope that anything of this helps.

Comment: You are being misled by the debugger output, Collection already has a visualizer, it is Collection.CollectionDebugView.  Its internal structure is *very* different, use a good decompiler to see what it really looks like.

Comment: @HansPassant CollectionDebugView seems to be part of Markup-Programming http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/. Can you ,please, confirm that it is able to acces keys in a VisualBasic.Collection? Is it worth trying/reading from this point of view?

Comment: No, that's not it.  As I said, you need a decompiler to see it, use ILSpy or Reflector.  The whole quest is very murky to me, I don't see how you are going to replace the visualizer, it is hard-baked and you can't change the attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant I apologize. I am probably not expensing myself clearly enough. I am writing a Debugger Visualiser (like e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13127/Create-a-Debugger-Visualizer-in-10-Lines-of-Code) and I want to list keys of objects in VisualBasic.Collection. I have all the source code of application I am debugging available.

Comment: @varocarbas I did it, but the solution is ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VisualBasic.Collection` has an undocumented private method `InternalItemsList` which allows reading keys besides values.  The type of  `InternalItemsList` is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.FastList` which does not seem to be Enumerable but has a method `Item` which returns items with a *zero based* index. The type of those items is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.Node`. An item has two private properties `m_Value` and `m_Key`. And here we are.

Following code illustrates how to convert `VisualBasic.Collection`  to `List(Of KeyValuePair`.

```
Dim flg As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic
Dim InternalList As Object = col.GetType.GetMethod("InternalItemsList", flg).Invoke(col, Nothing)
Dim res As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))
For qq As Integer = 0 To col.Count - 1
    Dim Item As Object = InternalList.GetType.GetProperty("Item", flg).GetValue(InternalList, {qq})
    Dim Key As String = Item.GetType.GetField("m_Key", flg).GetValue(Item)
    Dim Value As Object = Item.GetType.GetField("m_Value", flg).GetValue(Item)
    res.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)(Key, Value))
Next
```

I know that using undocumented functions is not safe but it is for internal use only and only solution I have managed to find.

Comment: Ugly?! Why? There is nothing more beautiful than something working :) this is a certainly interesting solution, thanks for sharing. This might be useful for someone else, can you please add one clarification? As explained in our discussion above, the Collection is, in theory, the equivalent to a List, that is, a KeyValuePair where the Key is an integer (or better: nothing). This VB version behaves also as a Dictionary (KeyValuePair as you are using it). So... you should update your code to account for both realities (or, at least, mention that this might happen), that is:

Comment: With `Dim col As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()` you can have `col.Add("123", "key")`, where your code would work fine (this "special" Collection as Dictionary); but also you can have `col.add("123")` (which is the standard behaviour as List). In this second case, the Key is Null and thus your code wouldn't work. Please reflect these two situations in your answer such that it will be a truly valuable information for someone (well... honestly, this does not sound as a too urgent/popular need ;)).

Comment: @varocarbas The the situation with collection as a list is handled correctly. The key is `Nothing` in this case. Please note that the example creates a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))` which allows a key be nothing not a 'Dictionary' which doesn't. I have added more detailed explanation.

Comment: OK. The whole point of my comment was just highlighting this issue: this Collection has not necessarily a Key. Actually, not having a Key is almost its standard behaviour (and this is the whole complication of what you requested: the default properties do not provide support for the Key-Value duplicity).

Comment: Still works to this day. I tweaked this and put in a Github Gist including iterators for KeyValuePairs, Values and Keys here: https://gist.github.com/JavaScriptDude/c1d9302932293aac9b40857639de1540  .